# Lyrics sync with running audio

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, ipad

Does anyone have any idea on how to keep text in sync with audio such that as the audio progresses, the lyrics that are being sung are what is being displayed onscreen?

What I actually want, is my audio file to be playing playing and at the same time the lyrics of that audio file will be highlighted. (Similar to a karaoke machine.)

Answer (score 1):

[Soundhound](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/soundhound/id355554941?mt=8) can show lyrics in real time.

Comment: as your suggestion I saw that app.Its awsm but actual as I want.Its simply Display Lyrics not sync with audio.